# C++ Linux: Game server crashing on virtual class return function pointer

Tags: c++, linux, crash

I'm having a small problem in here which I can't seem to reproduce under Windows.
Basically what is happening is that my program is crashing at this line:

```
Thing* thing = g_game.getThingFromPlayer(Player, Head);
if (thing && thing->getItem()) { // Crash line
    // Some code
}
```

I have two classes; a virtual one called Thing, and a normal class called Item which bases from Thing, Thing is a virtual class used among all my other game server classes like NPC & Monster.

In Thing virtual class there's this:

```
virtual Item* getItem() {return NULL;};
virtual const Item* getItem() const {return NULL;};
```

And in Item class there's this:

```
virtual Item* getItem() { return this; };
virtual const Item* getItem() const { return this; };
```

For some reason after calling `thing->getItem()` my program would segmentation fault under Linux, but under Windows it works just fine, Thing isn't `null` BTW.

I wonder, what could the reason be ?

By the way, here's the backtrace log:

```
#0  Game::playerUseItem (this=0x7bbf40, playerId=268460163, pos=..., stackPos=1 '\001', index=0 '\000', spriteId=1638) at game.cpp:2550
#1  0x00000000004a26c5 in operator() (this=0x2bf89c8) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:760
#2  operator() (this=0x2bf89c0) at tasks.h:44
#3  Dispatcher::dispatcherThread (p=0x7bbe80) at tasks.cpp:87
#4  0x00007ffff7e7c629 in boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_proxy (param=<optimized out>) at libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:121
#5  0x00007ffff71e3b50 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff642ee6d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: When dereferencing a pointer *sometimes* segfaults, it often means that it's a dangling pointer.  The memory pointed to **may** still be accessible and correct after the `delete`.

Comment: Q: When you created subclasses of class :"Item", did you double-check to make sure that you also created *virtual destructors* as needed?  Look here for more details: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html

Comment: Yes, subclass destructors are available on each class, what are the chances of it being just a memory issue or compile issue under Linux? It's working perfectly under Windows.

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro: Since you're using raw pointers, the likelihood of it being a memory problem in your code is far, far greater than that of a Linux compile problem.